# How to keep service alive even after activity destroyed?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

Here i am running a service for music play back. 
This code snippet is in my onStart() method of my Activity

```
if(musicServiceStartIntent == null) {
            musicServiceStartIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
            startService(musicServiceStartIntent);
            bindService(musicServiceStartIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
```

First i'm starting my service then binding it. And i am calling unbindservice() in onDestroy() method. My Activity got destroyed and service stopped.

```
unbindService(musicConnection);
```

Manifest file declaration

```
<service android:name=".Services.MusicService"/>
```

How can i keep my service running in background even after activity destroyed. I refer  few threads of StackOverflow but they are not helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895872/how-to-keep-a-service-with-listeners-alive-after-unbind-in-android Try this. This worked for me

Comment: don't unbind the service on Ondestroy() and then also destroyed then make service sticky.

Comment: i tried your answer. if i dont unbind my service onDestroy(), it gives error.

Comment: @JayGhosh: look at my code snippet. i wrote it as you suggested. But not working for me.... :(

Comment: What is the purpose of having your Service bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your service in startForeground, using Notification you can keep your service alive..

Comment: it helps.. your answer not always helpful. i want to run this service continuously when my activity running and after destroyed.

Comment: than you must start your service in foreground

Comment: how to start service in foreground? i am calling liike this startService(intent);

Comment: Your suggestion working for me. Please edit your answer i will mark it as correct answer. Thanks.. :D

Comment: On android devices with lot of RAM, you're not required to put service foreground, but it'll make it more resilient. If service is using intents, `registerReciever` in separate ServiceHandler! ServiceHandler will prevent crashing your service when receiving intent coming after your Activity was destroyed by user/system. Example of such a service: https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/master/android/plugin/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/LocationService.java

Answer (score 3):

You just need to start the service, don't bind it to activity lifecycle

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeService.class);
startService(intent);
```

And your service can use START_STICKY / START_REDELIVER_INTENT to make sure that your service will be re-created when the android system kill your service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   //other code
   return START_STICKY;
}
```

If needed you can use Service.startForeground(notificationId, notification) to make sure that your service will not be killed by the system

Comment: did you mention startForeground?

Comment: I've posted exactly the same answer, try to look carefully

Comment: i have posted all possible answers, look again

Comment: with a simple example

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground.
A music player that plays music from a service should be set to run in the foreground, because the user is explicitly aware of its operation. The notification in the status bar might indicate the current song and allow the user to launch an activity to interact with the music player.
To request that your service run in the foreground, call `startForeground()`.

Answer (score 0):

`return service.START_STICKY` or `service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT` in `onStartCommand`

Comment: start_sticky means that activity will be recreated after it has been killed by Android. Take into account that service can be killed

Comment: @alexeypolusov **START_STICKY** has nothing to do with Activity!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I meant service, sorry.

Comment: try this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Answer (score 0):

There is three important tricks:

1. Call startForegroundService which creates a long running service not limited to the binded context and make a promise to call startForeground later.
2. Return START_STICKY in onStartComand
3. Call startForeground with a notification as promised in (1).

For example, if you want to run a TimerService, in your TimerActivity you will do:

```
private var timerService: TimerService? = null

private val timerServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {

    override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        val binder = service as TimerService.Binder
        timerService = binder.getService()
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    startButton.setOnClickListener {
        timerService?.startTimer(60L, 0L)
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    Intent(this, TimerService::class.java).also {
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, it) // that's the first trick
        bindService(it, timerServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }
}
```

Your TimerService will be something like that:

```
class TimerService : Service() {

    private val binder = Binder()

    private var serviceLooper: Looper? = null

    private var serviceHandler: ServiceHandler? = null

    private var timer: CountDownTimer? = null

    private val notificationUtil by lazy {
        NotificationUtil(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND).apply {
            start()
            serviceLooper = looper
            serviceHandler = ServiceHandler(looper)
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = binder

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val timerRemaining = intent?.getLongExtra(EXTRA_REMAINING, 0) ?: 0L
        if (timerRemaining != 0L) {
            serviceHandler?.obtainMessage()?.also { msg ->
                msg.arg1 = startId
                msg.data.putLong(EXTRA_REMAINING, timerRemaining)
                serviceHandler?.sendMessage(msg)
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY // that's the second trick
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        timer?.cancel()
    }

    fun startTimer(secondsRemaining: Long, id: Long) {
        Intent(this, TimerService::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_REMAINING, secondsRemaining)
        }.also {
            onStartCommand(it, 0, id.toInt())
        }
    }

    fun stopTimer() {
        timer?.cancel()
    }

    fun updateNotification(secondsRemaining: Long){
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationUtil.CHANNEL_ID_TIMER)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(0)
                .setContentTitle(secondsRemaining.formatSeconds())
                .setContentText("Timer")
                .setContentIntent(notificationUtil.getPendingIntentWithStack(this, TimerActivity::class.java))
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build()
        startForeground(NotificationUtil.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification) // that's the last trick
    }

    private fun sendMessage(remaining: Long) {
        Intent(TimerService::class.java.simpleName).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_REMAINING, remaining)
        }.also {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(it)
        }
    }

    private inner class ServiceHandler(looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {

        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            val secondsRemaining = msg.data.getLong(EXTRA_REMAINING)
            notificationUtil.showTimerStarted(secondsRemaining)

            timer = object : CountDownTimer(secondsRemaining * 1000, 1000) {

                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    Log.i(this::class.java.simpleName, "tick ${(millisUntilFinished / 1000L).formatSeconds()}")
                    updateNotification(millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                    sendMessage(millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    Log.i(this::class.java.simpleName, "finish")
                    notificationUtil.showTimerEnded()
                    sendMessage(0)
                    stopSelf()
                }
            }.start()
        }
    }

    inner class Binder : android.os.Binder() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        fun getService(): TimerService = this@TimerService
    }

    companion object {

        const val EXTRA_REMAINING = "EXTRA_REMAINING"
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1 // cannot be 0

        fun Long.formatSeconds(): String {
            val s = this % 60
            val m = this / 60 % 60
            val h = this / (60 * 60) % 24
            return if (h > 0) String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s)
            else String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s)
        }
    }

}
```