# Are there any benefits to using Context.startForegroundService(Intent) instead of Context.startService(Intent) for foreground services?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I read in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) that `Context.startForegroundService()` has an implicit promise that the started service will call `startForeground()`. However, since Android O is coming out with changes to background and foreground services, are there any other performance improvements that it has compared to using the older `startService()` method, or is it just best practice going forward?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's  about neither performance improvements, nor benefits, nor best practice.

Starting from API 26, system just doesn't allow a background app to create a background service.

So, if your app is in the background (you're welcome to do the same if it's in the foreground as well), you ***have to*** to use `Context.startForegroundService(Intent)` instead of the former `startService(Intent)`. The service must then call `startForeground(int, Notification)` within first 5 seconds after it has started, otherwise system will stop the service.

It should also be mentioned that there is information that the old way with starting a service with `startService(Intent)` from a background app still works on the current release of Android Oreo, but it will be fixed soon.

Hence, starting from the API 26, you want to use new `Context.startForegroundService(Intent)` method instead of `startService(Intent)` whenever you want to start a foreground service.

Comment: `there is information that old way with starting a service with startService(Intent) from a bacjground app still works` Is there a source?

Comment: Does it mean that I have to check whether API >= 26 and if yes, then call `startForegroundService()`, otherwise call `startService()`?

Comment: @scarface Yes, you have to check it, otherwise an exception would be thrown when attempting to call the `startService()` method from a background app. But I believe you couid avoid a manual code for that check if you'd use a standard Android `compat` lib.

Comment: The thing is that those 5 seconds are a very short period of time. If system is busy, a Service object that is supposed to call startForeground might not be called for more than 5 seconds, and it will occasionally (not always) crash the app. Very poor design on Google's side, and it's not clear how to fix. Any ideas?

Comment: @OlegGryb Have you tried to find an answer to your question in Android bug tracker or maybe posted a bug there to see what the Android team could advice on this specific issue?

Comment: Here is a bigger discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground where people were opening bugs, but Google didn't do anything to fix. There are many answers, but none really addresses the issue. I do have this problem in my app and it does crash once in a month. Publishing stack trace here won't help.

Comment: @OlegGryb Ok, glad you've found some info regarding your issue.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov yes, I've described my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground/56534432#56534432

Answer (score 4):

As I've explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground/56534432#56534432), startForegroundService has a serious problem that will inevitably lead to infrequent ANR's. Since this problem can't be fixed at an app level, startForegroundService should not be used. I switched to [JobScheduler and JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) model to implement the same functionality.

The latter model works well so far and I didn't see app crashes in Play Store anymore. The new model is quite different though and I've spent two days re-factoring existing code based on startForegroundService, but it has definitely paid off.