# android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: null

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

```
 05-20 17:25:42.825 7493-7493/com.xxxxxx.xxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxxxxx.xxxxx, PID: 7493
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: null
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
            05-20 17:25:42.826 7493-7493/com.xxxxxx.xxxxx E/UncaughtException: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: null
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: solve the problem by using below code..,

Comment: String channelId;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startForegroundNew() {

            channelId = createNotificationChannel();
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .build();
            startForeground(101, notification);
    }

Comment: @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private String createNotificationChannel(){
        String channelId = "my_service";
        String channelName = "My Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(channelId,channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Comment: notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        return channelId;
    }

Comment: use this solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531742/startforeground-fail-after-upgrade-to-android-8-1

Comment: Already solved the problem