# Application is not receiving location updates while its in background

Tags: android, gps, background-service, locationlistener

The Main aim of my application is to trace the path on the map in realtime which the user traverses regardless of the fact that the user has opened the application or not.

With the help of a service I am able to request the location updates i.e. the current location of the user and broadcast them to my MainActivity to trace the path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ForegroundService` instead of `Service`and call `startForegroundService()` when you want to start it.

Next in this new `ForegroundService` in onCreate method call `startForeground()`. With `startForeground` you have to pass a `notification` to inform the user that service is `running`.

Another problem is that many devices use different kind of tricks to protect battery and try to kill working services.

To track location for a long time You should try to get users permission to disable battery optimization.

Comment: I did as instructed regarding the ForegroundService but it shows the following error : Bad notification for startForeground

Comment: Did you use channel? Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: Go through following link where you can find a solution to the crash you are facing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531742/startforeground-fail-after-upgrade-to-android-8-1

Comment: Wasn't doing this earlier but yeah i did use a channel now, The Notification works fine but the issue stills remains unsolved. I still cant trace the path in background.

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: You can also try to use broadcast receiver to restart the service when it's get killed. https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

Comment: I am using POCO F1 and to mimic the movement of the user i am using a third Party Application to obtain a Mock Location. 
I am not using the Broadcast Receiver to restart the application,For that i have stored a boolean in the Shared Preferences so whenever my application is killed, i check the Status of the service.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

Comment: Did you try to use your app on emulator?

Comment: idk if it will be working with the Foreground Service, but it sure is now working with the normal service with just one limitation. I can successfully trace the user traversed path ONLY the app is in background. For the time being, I am satisfied with this.