# Bad Notification for startForeground error, can not see a fix

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-sensors

The error is as below, i am trying to start this service to provide ongoing sensor updates, the goal is to log out the sensor events until i stop the service, I simply need to be able to start this service collect the data until i stop the service:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
```

The Service that is started is:

```
public class SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SensorService";

    private static final int SCREEN_OFF_RECEIVER_DELAY = 100;

    //10ms minimum due to Android/hardware limitations 9 gives more accurate 10ms intervals
    private final short POLL_FREQUENCY = 9;

    private long lastUpdate = -1;
    private long curTime;
    public static long fps;

    public Messenger messageHandler;

    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    private WakeLock wakeLock = null;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private Sensor sensor;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private Sensor gyroscope;
    private Sensor pressure;
    private Sensor magnetic;

    private float[] accelerometerMatrix = new float[3];
    private float[] gyroscopeMatrix = new float[3];
    private float[] pressureMatrix = new float[1];
    private float[] magneticMatrix = new float[3];

    private void registerListener() {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, pressure, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetic, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    private void unregisterListener() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onReceive(" + intent + ")");

            if (!Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                return;
            }

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Runnable executing...");
                    unregisterListener();
                    registerListener();
                }
            };

            new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, SCREEN_OFF_RECEIVER_DELAY);
        }
    };

/*   private void sendMessage(String state) {
        Message message = Message.obtain();
        switch (state) {
            case "HIDE" :
                message.arg1 = 0;
                break;
            case "SHOW":
                message.arg1 = 1;
                break;
        }
        try {
            messageHandler.send(message);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        sensor = event.sensor;

        //Store data
        int i = sensor.getType();
        if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            accelerometerMatrix = event.values;
        }else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            gyroscopeMatrix = event.values;
        }else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_PRESSURE) {
            pressureMatrix = event.values;
        }
        else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_MAGNETIC) {
            magneticMatrix = event.values;
        }

        curTime = event.timestamp; // nanoseconds

        // One update every POLL_FREQUENCY converted to nano
        if((curTime - lastUpdate) > POLL_FREQUENCY*1000000) {
            fps = ((curTime-lastUpdate)/1000000);
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            Log.d(TAG, "The data " + accelerometerMatrix[0]+
                    accelerometerMatrix[0]+
                    accelerometerMatrix[1]+
                    accelerometerMatrix[2]+
                    gyroscopeMatrix[0]+
                    gyroscopeMatrix[1]+
                    gyroscopeMatrix[2]+
                    magneticMatrix[0]+
                    accelerometerMatrix[1]+
                    magneticMatrix[2]
                    );

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        startForeground(1, new Notification());

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        assert sensorManager != null;
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(MainActivity.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        gyroscope = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(MainActivity.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        pressure = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(MainActivity.TYPE_PRESSURE);
        magnetic = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(MainActivity.TYPE_MAGNETIC);

        PowerManager wManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        assert wManager != null;
        wakeLock = wManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Application:TAG");

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));

        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startForeground(Process.myPid(), new Notification());
        registerListener();
        wakeLock.acquire();

        //Message handler for progress dialog
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        assert extras != null;
        //messageHandler = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //Show dialog
        //sendMessage("SHOW");

        //Unregister receiver and listener prior to executor shutdown
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        unregisterListener();

        //Prevent new tasks from being added to thread
        executor.shutdown();
        Log.d(TAG, "Executor shutdown is called");

        //Create new thread to wait for executor to clear queue and wait for termination
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Wait for all tasks to finish before we proceed
                    while (!executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for current tasks to finish");
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "No queue to clear");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught while waiting for finishing executor tasks");
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

                if (executor.isTerminated()) {
                    //Stop everything else once the task queue is clear
                   // wakeLock.release();
                    stopForeground(true);

                    //Dismiss progress dialog
                    //sendMessage("HIDE");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

I hope someone can see the obvious error i am probably making. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i thinks this answer can help you:

[Take a look, :D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531742/startforeground-fail-after-upgrade-to-android-8-1)

Did you add the permission below in you android-manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I do already have the permission in my manifest, i have looked at a few answers, but have not found anything that helps me. Thank you for the suggestion and trying to help.