# Bad notification for startForeground error: invalid service notification

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I get this error when starting a foreground service:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid service notification: Notification(channel=channelSocketIOService pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid service notification: Notification(channel=channelSocketIOService pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1945)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 /end;
```

In service class:

```
private void RegisterForegroundService()
{
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, $"ServiceNotifications")
        .SetOngoing(true)
        .Build();

    StartForeground(462, notification);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is that the full Notification code? You need to set the title, etc... so the user can visual see what app is running the service.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

- Go to Android-Settings > Build
- Turn off code optimization
- Build the solution
- Turn code optimization back on

Worked for me but don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a default notification channel in Android 8 and above. Or else you will get this error.
More details at
[startForeground fail after upgrade to Android 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531742/startforeground-fail-after-upgrade-to-android-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

From document [Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) ,we will know :

> Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be
> assigned to a channel. For each channel, you can set the visual and
> auditory behavior that is applied to all notifications in that
> channel. Then, users can change these settings and decide which
> notification channels from your app should be intrusive or visible at
> all.

In xamarin android platform, you can check document [Notifications in Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications).

And there is a sample included in above code.  You can check it here : https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/LocalNotifications .

The main code is:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    // Unique ID for our notification: 
    static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "location_notification";
    internal static readonly string COUNT_KEY = "count";

    // Number of times the button is tapped (starts with first tap):
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        CreateNotificationChannel();

        // Display the "Hello World, Click Me!" button and register its event handler:
        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
    }

    // Handler for button click events.
    void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Pass the current button press count value to the next activity:
        var valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
        valuesForActivity.PutInt(COUNT_KEY, count);

        // When the user clicks the notification, SecondActivity will start up.
        var resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));

        // Pass some values to SecondActivity:
        resultIntent.PutExtras(valuesForActivity);

        // Construct a back stack for cross-task navigation:
        var stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Class.FromType(typeof(SecondActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

        // Create the PendingIntent with the back stack:            
        var resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int) PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        // Build the notification:
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                      .SetAutoCancel(true) // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
                      .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
                      .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked") // Set the title
                      .SetNumber(count) // Display the count in the Content Info
                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click) // This is the icon to display
                      .SetContentText($"The button has been clicked {count} times."); // the message to display.

        // Finally, publish the notification:
        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());

        // Increment the button press count:
        count++;
    }

    void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }

        var name = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.channel_name);
        var description = GetString(Resource.String.channel_description);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationImportance.Default)
                      {
                          Description = description
                      };

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```