# Context.startForegroundService did not then call Service.startForeground

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

It's mine BroadcastReciever class. The class working on Boot phone status.

Code ;

```
public class BroadCastRecieverBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent ıntent) {
        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(ıntent.getAction()))
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, GPSTracker.class));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
                context.startService(new Intent(context, GPSTracker.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get This Error ;

```
     android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()


    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1792)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                            

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)                                                   

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)                                        

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                   

        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

It doesn't work on Android Oreo now. I don't know what is the mistake of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground)

Comment: Check out here! [Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528446/9636618)

Comment: Finally the issue is solved for our application https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754189/12228079

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to official document of Android 8.0 [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

> Android 8.0 introduces the new method
>   **startForegroundService()** to start a new service in the foreground.
>   After the system has created the service, the app has **five seconds** to
>   call the service's **startForeground()** method to show the new service's
>   user-visible notification. **If the app does not call startForeground()
>   within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the
>   app to be ANR.**

So, make sure you have started ongoing notification by calling [startForeground (int id, Notification notification)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) in  the `onCreate()` method of your service.

**Note:** Apps targeting API `Build.VERSION_CODES.P` or later must request the permission `Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` in order to use this API.

Comment: Apps targeting `API 27` but getting crashes on `Build.VERSION_CODES.P`

Comment: @Sagar Have you started the notification using `startForeground(int id, Notification notification)` method in your service class?

Comment: yes I have started the notification using `startForeground(int id, Notification notification)`

Comment: @Sagar Can you post a new question with your crash logs? Send me link of that, I will surely help you if I can.

Comment: i add this `android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` it's working

Comment: @GowthamanM have you experience any performance issue with adding that permission?

Comment: @LimyandiVicoTrico Becase of permission you will not get the performance issuse....There is issues in your service please check your service class

Comment: still it is not working