# App is getting crashed when service wants to stop

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I have started a service like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

But when I want to stop this service then I faced an error which is:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

To resolve this error I tried:
1.Used `stopSelf();` in onDestroy() method.
2. Used `startForeground(0, new Notification());` in the onCreate() method.

But the error still remains. I searched a lot on StackOverflow and android official websites also. Can't find any suitable answer to solve my problem. By the way, this error starts from Android OREO version.

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground

Comment: check here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76112072

Comment: Nilesh Rathod: Yes I checked this but not helped me.

Comment: on which Android version does it crash?

Comment: This is start from OREO 8.0

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

> "Android 8.0 introduces the new method startForegroundService() to
>   start a new service in the foreground. After the system has created
>   the service, the app has five seconds to call the service's
>   startForeground() method to show the new service's user-visible
>   notification. If the app does not call startForeground() within the
>   time limit, the system stops the service and declares the app to be
>   ANR."