# Does a Web Worker run on the main ui android thread or a separate thread?

Tags: android, performance, web-worker, android-8.0-oreo, webchromeclient

I have an OLD application for the Android that uses  WebChromeClient

> public class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient

to run a web page on the Android *as an application*.  *The original intent was to keep the displays for apps (browser, ios, and android) identical*. 
As usually happens, the application grew more complicated over time (5 years) and a local web database is used to store state for faster startup.

With the latest version of the Android Oreo OS, my app gets a ANR warning. I realize it is time to redesign but have a super tight schedule.  **If I move the initialization code (web database that uses callbacks (promises), ...) into a html 5 web worker, will that code run on a separate thread in Android application (other than the main ui thread?)**  Will this solve the ANR?  Or do I have to totally redesign?

> Does a Web Worker run on the main ui android thread or a separate thread?  BTW - how about in the latest IOS, are web workers run on the main thread or separate thread?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webview does not run on the Android UI thread.  The problem had nothing to do with the web view at all.  Instead the ANR is a known Android Oreo change.  And I was able to fix it by following
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground)