# How to reproduce IllegalStateException Not allowed to start service Intent app is in background

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

I'm trying to remove this bug by upgrading how my app handles receiving messages and doing background work, but I can't cause the bug to happen without just waiting for an hour or so.

How can I reproduce this? I've tried making a project that does nothing but launch a service as soon as the app is paused but works just fine. I've tried `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle`, `adb shell dumpsys battery unplug` and `adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> true`. No luck.

If I can't force this error to happen, I don't have a way to verify my fixes are correct.

Comment: You have to use `startForegroundService` and promote your service to foreground within five seconds of starting it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047542/9241978).

Comment: Post your log error here

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the command below?

```
adb shell am make-uid-idle [--user user-id | all | current] package-name
```

Source: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/app_mgmt#testing-app-restrictions