# ANR : Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(), InvisibleToUser

Tags: android, service

I am getting this ANR in our app . Whenver I am calling startForegroundService() , in the start of the onCreate(), I am elevating the service to foreground with a notification .

Is there any way I can avoid this ANR ? This contributes to 90% of the ANR that we are getting .

[I looked into this question but for them they are saying its causing a crash for them , while for us its an ANR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Follow these links to see the examples of foreground services in android:
[Sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.4/Notifications/Foreground)

[Sample 2](https://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/)

Comment: I understand how foreground services work.Its already implemented and its in production for the last 3 months. Our  app has more than 1 million DAU  with 99.90% ANR free sessions. The ANR that I added in the question is the leading cause of the remaining 0.10% of ANRs.