# How to make foreground Services work in MIUI?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I've been messing around with android services and facing a problem while running foreground Services in **MIUI 10**(Testing Device: *Redmi note 5 pro*)

Basically Service runs as long as the user is interacting with activity but as soon as user kills activity, foreground service also gets killed.

I read some other answers regarding the same issues,

> which state that in devices like Xaomi, Oppo, lenovo, LG, honor etc. 
>   You need to enable "AutoRun" permission for the app

Which I tried with no success. I also tried the following with no success at all:

1. Disabled MIUI optimization
2. Disabled Power saving
3. Removed Battery restrictions for the app
4. Freed the memory *(Total: 3GB, Available:
   2GB)*

---

What worked for me was enabling the: *"Don't keep activites"* in the *Developer options* but in real world application you probably wouldn't ask users to enable this option since it affects user experience.

[image: Developer options MIUI 10]

By the way, I tested my app in other devices such as pixel, nexus etc(Android studio emulators) And They all worked fine. It's only my device which is causing this issue.

*Download link for the app for debugging purposes: https://anonfile.com/d4k511p1bd/app-debug_apk*

**Source Code**

*File: MainActivity.java*

```
package com.myname.foregroundserviceexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editTextInput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_input);
    }

    public void startService(View v) {
        String input = editTextInput.getText().toString();

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
    }

    public void stopService(View v) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }

}
```

File: ExampleService.java

```
package com.myname.foregroundserviceexample;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import static com.myname.foregroundserviceexample.App.CHANNEL_ID;


public class ExampleService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
        // Starting Foreground Service
        startForeground(1, notification);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

File: App.java

```
package com.myname.foregroundserviceexample;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;


public class App extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Example Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

I know there's a way around this by enabling "Don't keep activities" in Developing options but I genuinely don't want the user to enable this in their device, Also I would gladly accept any alternative or code improvements to make the foreground Service work in MIUI 10.

Thankyou

**EDIT:**

Here's the project link: https://anonfile.com/y5Rd4bp3b9/ForegroundServiceExample_zip

And this is the tutorial I was following on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbpD5RZtbCc

Comment: I can't see `startForeground()` anywhere in your service.

Comment: @egoldx Actually `startForeground()` is there in the original code, I must've accidentally removed it while uploading source code in here. But yeah It is there in the _ExampleService.java_

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to call [`Service#startForeground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) at the begining of your service creation in the `onCreate`/`onStartIntent`

See this post [Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but actually "startForeground()" is there in the original code I just messed up my source code in here and now I fixed the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing an error like this.

`Permission Denial: startForeground requires android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE`

Then you have to add this in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"></uses-permission>
```

Hope it's work for you.