# Unable to start a Service in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle):

> A foreground process is one that is required for what the user is
>   currently doing. Various application components can cause its
>   containing process to be considered foreground in different ways. **A
>   process is considered to be in the foreground** if any of the following
>   conditions hold:
>
> It is running an Activity at the top of the screen that the user is interacting with (its onResume() method has been called).
>
> **> It has a BroadcastReceiver that is currently running (its
>   BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() method is executing).**
>
> It has a Service that is currently executing code in one of its callbacks (Service.onCreate(), Service.onStart(), or
>   Service.onDestroy()).

I use API 27 and when i run the start service, the process is in the foreground and thus the service should start. But instead i get the error which i**s the restriction of Android Oreo**. Are the docs inaccurate?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // assumes WordService is a registered service


    context.startService(new Intent(context, HelloService.class));

}


E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 26026
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.paourissi.testapp.MyReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.testapp/.HelloService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{bee03a7 u0a82 RCVR bg:+1m19s133ms idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
```

Comment: try `startForgroundService` in oreo

Comment: @Praveen If i hadnt added them the error would be much different

Comment: @code4rox A lot of problems with startForgroundService  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground

Comment: That definitely feels like a documentation bug.

Comment: Use android [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) to start service