# Service Foreground crash issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am facing this issue in service running on background. It will automatic crash in background. Where is the issue i couldn't find out.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): 
ServiceRecord{e4c7ef5 u0 com.clap.find.my.mobile.alarm.sound/.service.BatteryAlertService}
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2137)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Answer (score 1):

kindly refer to this link and you will definitely know what going on and reason for your crash .

[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground)

if you can opt below criteria then u can probably solve your fix .

Why this issue is happening is because Android framework can't guarantee your service get started within 5 second but on the other hand framework does have strict limit on foreground notification must be fired within 5 seconds, without checking if framework had tried to start the service.

This is definitely a framework issue, but not all developers facing this issue are doing their best:

1. **startForeground** a notification must be in both **onCreate** and **onStartCommand**, because if your service is already created and somehow your activity is trying to start it again, **onCreate** won't be called.
2. notification ID must not be 0 otherwise same crash will happen even it's not same reason.
3. **stopSelf** must not be called before **startForeground**.

With all above 3 this issue can be reduced a bit but still not a fix, the real fix or let's say workaround is to downgrade your target sdk version to 25.**

Comment: 1. why not only in onStartCommand? is it not the same?