# Service did not call startForeground even though it does

Tags: android, android-service

I am getting an error that does not make sense to me

The error I get is

> RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then
> call Service.startForeground()

I have a BroadcastReceiver that gets fore from an exact alarm and that receiver starts a service to do some short work

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        context.startForegroundService(Intent(context, RestartService::class.java))
    }else{
        context.startService(Intent(context, RestartService::class.java))
    }
}
```

then in my service class I make sure to start foreground

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Create a new notification channel
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        // Create a notification
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app)
            .build()

        // Start the service in the foreground
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }
```

as you can see I am calling `startForeground` in my onStartCommand

I know about the background restrictions but for testing I have enabled my app to `Draw over other apps` which the documentation says would allow me to start a service and an activity when the app is in the background as well as having this come from an exact alarm. This error happens when app is in the foreground too

I dont know what I am missing here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground)

Comment: no I have already looked at that and it does not provide anything that I am not already doing

Comment: Plus the fact that this is happening while the app is in the foreground makes no sense

Comment: I’m convinced this API just doesn’t consistently work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my code in `onCreate` was completing too fast and the service was unable to call `startForeground` before I was stopping the service causing the exception

Comment: what is the solution for that avoid this kind of error.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you resolved it @tyczj , I am facing same issue

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you solved this issue? seems like the same is happening to me but I don't understand how to fix that