# How to run service when application goes background?

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I hope this message finds you well. I am seeking guidance on implementing a foreground service in my application with the following requirements:

Periodically download data from an API (e.g., every 15 or 60 seconds).
Display a notification if new data is available.
Automatically stop the service when the notification is opened.
Restart(run again) the service when the app is brought to the background or killed.
I have a few questions and considerations regarding the implementation:

Best Approach:
What is the best approach to implement this functionality? I am currently considering using the `onStop()` method in the activity to trigger a `coroutine worker` that will start the service. The service would then employ repeated logic every 15 seconds to download data or use a `coroutine worker` for API calls. I am thinking of using a `LifecycleService` for this purpose. Do you recommend this approach, or is there a more efficient way to achieve the desired functionality?
Is it possible if I try using **onStop** method and this method will be late and won't run because at first activity will be destroyed?

Handling Errors:
I have encountered a 5-second error with the foreground service in my previous implementation. How can I avoid this issue? I found a related question on Stack Overflow (link provided). Do you have any recommendations to prevent such errors?

[Link to Stack Overflow Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground]

LocationService:
I also have a LocationService that needs to function similarly, but it should never be terminated. Is it safe to run two separate services (one for location and one for API calls and notifications)? Alternatively, would it be better to combine these functionalities into a single service? If so, should I use `LifecycleService` or just a regular Service?

`class LocationService : Service(), LocationListener`

Comment: "What is the best approach to implement this functionality?" -- the best approach is to completely rethink your plan. Users **hate** apps like what you describe, because such apps cause phone batteries to drain rapidly. As a result, Google and device manufacturers have taken [many steps](https://dontkillmyapp.com/) to prevent apps from doing what you describe. Please use Firebase Cloud Messaging to *push data down when it changes*, rather than attempting to keep operating at full power continuously.

Comment: THis is why push messaging exists.  Rather than poll for data every few seconds, push data when there's a change.  This saves battery life for the user and a TON of cost on your server responding to redundant querries that will kill you at scale.

Comment: I now, I rather prefer and always make apps like backend has communication with firebase and if it changes I received information in 'onMessagedReceived' method, but let's say I can't do it like this, which option will you recommend? and what is your proposition to make it quite right?

Comment: My main worries are about can I launch service in onStop method or it is a possibility like it won't run like I have commented. Thanks for any advices. You are right, but I am looking the other way. Thanks