I have Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException
I got exception in firebase: Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

Device: Vivo 1802, android 8.1

 Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then   call Service.startForeground()
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1886)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6759)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)

I'm using below code to start service:
if (isSdkO()) {
 requireContext().startForegroundService(intent)
 else {
 requireContext().startService(intent)


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground

Does this answer your question? Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
